# How can I do IP camera connection verification

Tags: python, python-3.x, ip, ip-camera

I have a code block like the one below, but I cannot verify connection. If the camera cannot be connected, I want to print a connection error. Can you help me.

```
import numpy as np
import cv2
cap = cv2.VideoCapture('rtsp://admin:12345678@192.168.102.114:554/ch01_sub.264')
fourcc = cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc(*'XVID')
out = cv2.VideoWriter('ouput.avi', fourcc, 20.0, (640,480))

while(cap.isOpened()):
    ret, frame = cap.read()
    if ret == True:
        frame = cv2.flip(frame,0)
        out.write(frame)
        
        cv2.imshow('frame',frame)
        if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
           break
    else:
       break

cap.release()
out.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using `try`. The below code may not be exactly correct as I don't quite understand where it is failing, but should give you enough to get the idea.

```
    try: 
        while(cap.isOpened()):

           ret, frame = cap.read()
           frame = cv2.flip(frame,0)
           out.write(frame)
        
           cv2.imshow('frame',frame)

           if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
             break

    except: 
        print('Connection error')
```